# What's wrong on adding Days at this Date function?

Tags: javascript, date

This is my code:

```
var dat = new Date("24/03/2013");
dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + 7);
console.log(dat)
```

but it print `Tue Jan 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100`?

The date is wrong: should be 31/03/2013 (and I'd like to print it in this format).

Comment: Which browser are you using (if only so we can avoid it in future)? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My browser (Chrome) prints "Invalid date", but apparently yours interprets the initializing date in mm/dd/yyyy format instead of dd/mm/yyyy. Therefore it thinks it's the 3rd day of the 24th month of 2013, which is January 3rd, 2015.

I'm not sure why it would print it as January 6th if you add 7 days to it.

The safest way is to give the numbers explicitly:

```
var dat = new Date( 2013, 2, 24 );
```

Comment: It's worth noting that with this approach January is equal to 0 and December is equal to 11 - this isn't the case if you pass through a correctly formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

Change the format of your date to put the day *after* the month:

```
var dat = new Date("03/24/2013");
dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + 7);
console.log(dat)
```

For me this returns:

```
Sun Mar 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

Comment: No, it prints `Sat Nov 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100`

Comment: @markzzz Are you sure you have the code exactly as in the answer? Does http://jsfiddle.net/cCEJT/ also print Nov 2nd?

Comment: James, I'm not sure the _computer's_ date comes into it since you're not using the default constructor. But something's definitely screwy, I'll give you that.

Comment: @paxdiablo: ah of course, how silly! I'd assume that something is probably *different* with the tool @markzzz is using - it shouldn't have been able to process a month of 24. The [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) doesn't appear to mention which format is valid for `new Date()`, unfortunately, but `m(m)` followed by `d(d)` followed by `yy(yy)` does appear to be the only year-month-day format Chrome accepts (you can use `/` or `-` as separators).

Answer (score 1):

You should have to give the month number first. Then you'll get the correct answer

Try this code

```
var dat = new Date("03/24/2013");
dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + 7);
var curr_date = dat.getDate();
var curr_month = dat.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = dat.getFullYear();
console.log(curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should print out your date *before* you add seven. I suspect it's being set to the 3<sup>rd</sup> day of the 24th month in 2013, which equates to somewhere close to January 2015.

That's why you're getting a date well advanced from the current one. Why it's giving you the 6<sup>th</sup> of January rather than the 10<sup>th</sup>, I'm not sure, but you can probably fix it just by changing your input string to the US format of `mm/dd/yyyy`, or using [a more explicit constructor that's not subject to misinterpretation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp):

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!!!

```
var aDate = new Date(2013,3,24);
        aDate.setDate(aDate.getDate() + 7); 
        var dateString = aDate.getDate() + "-" + aDate.getMonth() + "-" + aDate.getFullYear(); 
        alert(dateString);
```

Comment: Did you mean to put those args inside quotes?

Comment: ya..just appending with string

Comment: No, I meant in the date constructor.

Comment: sry. by adding quotes producing different result.. now its working fine by removing it.for details http://jsfiddle.net/VavXa/1/

Comment: It should be `2013, 2, 24` (months start from 0).

Comment: Yes, but note that `"03/24/2013"` is different than `2013, 3, 24`. In the string the month is interpreted as March and as a number it's interpreted as April.